# An Algorithm for Predicting What an Object's Position will be in X Amount of Seconds

Tags: algorithm, lua

Question: How would I figure out an algorithm for calculating the position of an object x amount of time before it gets there, within 200 milliseconds of time(or less) with current x,y and speed variables (although could be more variables) in the LUA programming language(examples of an algorithm helps me better than straight answers).

I'm trying to make a lua script to represent a prediction method for predicting the next x and y position of a bouncing ball relative to a player. However since the ball moves from one wall to the next in one frame (instantaneous), it gives me the x,y of the ball on one wall, and then when it bounces again (it has a 3-4 frame delay between bouncing and moving) it gives me the x,y of the ball on the other wall, but i'm wanting it to predict at what time (milliseconds) will the ball be in "player1's" position or field of view to which point it would do an action to hit the ball out of the way so it doesn't hit the player. I have the x and y values and I understand a distance formula I created a while ago:

```
    distance = math.sqrt((ballx-p1x)*(ballx-p1x)+(bally-p1y)*(bally-p1y))
end

          createHotkey(function(hk)
            local dx = readInteger("[ballcoords]+18")-readInteger("[p2coords]+18")
            local dy = readInteger("[ballcoords]+1c")-readInteger("[p2coords]+1c")

            if math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy) <= 9000000 and hitstun_countdown >= 0 and hitstun_countdown <= 1 then
              doKeyPress(VK_Z)
            end
          end, VK_F)
```

But i'm going into unknown territory, so I decided to ask for help here, thanks for everything!

Feel free to ask *any* questions.

EDIT #1: Found that I have a group of x and y values to work with, they are called xspeed, xspeed, these both become negative if going to the left, and become positive if going to the right and depend only on the x value.  Then we have yspeed, yspeed, they are both positive if going up, and both negative if going down and depend only on the y value. You can tell if the object is going crooked and what direction it is crooked by looking at if they are either negative or positive, all 4 negative = crooked to left and going up, all 4 positive = crooked right, going down, just wanted to add this as it may make things easier.

EDIT#2: If ball has infinite speed then one of the x' and one of the y' go to 0 and represent nothing, but the other x and y keep displaying the angle. I'm 100% sure that one x and y represent magnitude in the angle the others are going in,  the others represent angle, not necessarily speed.

Comment: what is the language? **R** or **Lua** ?

Comment: You can use Kalman Filters: http://www.bzarg.com/p/how-a-kalman-filter-works-in-pictures/

Comment: I feel it's too ridicolously easy to be the answer, but... what about `nextX = currentX + velX * time`?

Answer (score 0):

I personally haven't done much in this territory, but I do know what it's called: extrapolation.

Maybe the vocabulary can help you do the proper research.  I know that not knowing the proper vocabulary has always been a block for me when learning.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extrapolation

Comment: Well, since the object has infinite magnitude, i'm unsure what to do with this method.